# How to convert String to int Color value

Tags: android, kotlin, colors, gradient

I want to set background with gradient. This's my code:

```
val startColor = "0xFFAC235E"
val endColor = "0xFF640C35"
val gradient = GradientDrawable(
    GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
    intArrayOf(
        startColor.toInt(),
        endColor.toInt()
    )
)
view.background = gradient
```

and it through an exception:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0xFFAC235E"
```

If I replace **startColor = 0xFFAC235E**, the code above work fine. But that's not what I want.

I need put color as param String. Is there anyway to convert it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing 0x with #.

For ex:

```
startColor.replace("0x", "#")
```

Generally we define colors with hex color codes. So, I think this will work for you.

**Edit**

You have to parse the color string to convert it into integer.

```
Color.parseColor(startColor.replace("0x", "#"))
```

Comment: I tried it and still through error **NumberFormatException: For input string: "#FFAC235E"**. I think problem is not using 0x or #, it can't convert string to Int

Comment: I have edited my answer. Use Color.parseColor